# $f(x)=[x]+<x>^{0.5}$ Is this continuous and differentiable at $x=1$?

Tags: continuity

> $f(x)=[x]+<x>^{0.5}$ Is this continuous and differentiable at $x=1$?
>
> Where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function and $<x>$ represents the
>   integer part of x.

Please help with this.

Is it discontinuous because when $x=1-\varepsilon $ , $f(x)=0+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$

and when  $x=1+\varepsilon $ , $f(x)=1+\sqrt{\varepsilon}$

Comment: Both the answers you have received take $\lt x \gt$ as the fractional part of $x$.  Your question says it is the integer part, which would match $[x]$ as you have defined it.  If you meant $\lt x \gt$ to be the fractional part, please edit your post.  Your computation at $x=1+\varepsilon$ uses the fractional part.  Your computation at $x=1-\varepsilon$ does not use either one correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\,0 \le x < 1$,

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$$

For $1 \le x < 2$,

$$f(x) = 1 + \sqrt{x-1}$$

It follows that $f$ is continuous at $x=1$, since 
\begin{align*}
&\bullet\;f(1) = 1\\[4pt]
&\bullet\;\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\sqrt{x} = 1\\[4pt]
&\bullet\;\lim_{x \to 1^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}}1+\sqrt{x-1} = 1
\end{align*}

But $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}
\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} 
&=
\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}
\frac{\left(1 + \sqrt{h}\right)-1}{h}\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}
\frac{\sqrt{h}}{h}\\[4pt]
&=
\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}\\[4pt]
&=\infty
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The fractional part of $x$ is $\langle x\rangle=x-[x]$, so when $0<x<1$ then the integer part of $x$ is zero, while the fractional part of $x$ is $\langle x\rangle=x-[x]=x-0$. Hence $f(x)=0+\sqrt{x}$ for $0<x<1$. On the other hand, when $1\le x<2$ then the integer part of $x$ is $1$ and so fractional part of $x$ is $\langle x\rangle=x-[x]=x-1$. Hence, $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x-1}$. I'll leave it to you to check continuity and differentiability.

Comment: Is it continuous but not differentiable?

Comment: yes, it is continuous but not differentiable